# Alternative to Asterisk (*) in function definitions

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, variadic-functions, pylint

Pylint complains when I am using an asterisk in a function call

```
def f(*args):
    # Some code

f(1, 2, 3,)
```

The output given by pylint:

```
pylint failed:
Used * or ** magic (star-args)
```

Is there an alternative to using `*` in function definitions, that renders the same result?

I need the code to validate through pylint because it is a school assignment. I don't think it is a legit warning but I have to do as pylint says.

Comment: disable the warning.

Comment: Do you really mean to be calling `f` with a tuple? In your example call, thanks to the doubled parentheses, `args` will be a 1-tuple containing a 3-tuple.

Comment: @Blckknght Oh I am sorry, I did not intend for that. Thanks for your remark!

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I can't Disable the warning because I need the program to validate for a school assignment

Comment: The reasoning behind it is that, if you know what arguments you are getting, you should use named arguments because they're clearer. That's true, but using * and ** is also perfectly valid in many situations. I would ask my instructor about his/her opinion on this. Pylint is not meant to be followed blindly; it often flags things that are sometimes bad and sometimes OK.

Comment: Pylint star-args warning is deprecated as of  pylint 1.4.3. So pylint won't generate a warning if a recent version of pylint is used.

Answer (score 3):

Pylint is *highly configurable* and can be rather a nuisance when it comes to certain things. Even the [`star-args (W0142)` rule description](http://docs.pylint.org/features.html) shows it is merely a warning:

> *Used * or ** magic*. Used when a function or method is called using `*args` or `**kwargs` to dispatch arguments. This doesn’t improve readability and should be used with care.

Just disable the warning for functions where you are certain using `*args` is the correct thing to do, rather than try and work around PyLint:

```
def f(*args):  # pylint: disable=star-args
    # Some code
```

Your only alternative is to accept *one* argument that you treat as a sequence, then pass in a tuple or list instead:

```
def f(arg):
    # Some code

f((1, 2, 3))
```

but I seriously doubt you'll be failed for using a `# pylint disable=...` comment.

Comment: Thanks but I can't configure pylint as I want to because It is for school

Comment: @PandaDeTapas: you can use in-line comments.